# AWS Jupyter Notebook EC2 Instance: Getting error while reading pandas csv from S3

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook

While reading a CSV from S3, the kernel is restarting with the below pop up:

```
Kernel Restarting
The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

YOUR_ACCESS_KEY='******'
YOUR_SECRET_KEY='******'
YOUR_BUCKET='******'

client = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=YOUR_SECRET_KEY)
client.download_file(YOUR_BUCKET, 'test.csv','test.csv')
```

Error is thrown from the below line :

```
test_df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

But I can access other files such as a sample text file:

```
client.download_file(YOUR_BUCKET, 'sample.txt','sample.txt')
print(open('sample.txt').read())
```

I assumed this error was because of the huge size of the CSV file, but reading a 5MB CSV file is giving the same error.

Comment: error you mentioned is pertaining to the ipython notebook.. can you post error you got at the mentioned line?? And also read_csv function accepts exact filepath please check the downloaded file path and filepath in read_csv.

Comment: I have edited my question, yes Pandas read_csv needs exact path of the file but I am assuming after downloading a file as I did in my sample code the file gets loaded in memory as I did the same for sample.txt and I opened it successfully using open command, again I mentioned it in my code above.

Comment: @Bharathshetty thanks for noticing the typo , I have corrected it now, but the issue remains same.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be the bug with pyTorch.

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2784

Alternatives and multiple solutions discussed around there, the ticket is still open.

Hope it helps.